# React cannot find module 'stream'

Tags: reactjs

I had same issue before for modules crypto, https, http, zlib

I did config-overrides.js

```
 Object.assign(fallback, {
    stream:require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
    http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
    zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),  
  });
```

And issue was solved

But when I am trying use this package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mexc-api

I got again, even when I have override for stream

```
Cannot find module 'stream'
```

My package.json

https://gist.github.com/RuslanMirov/92dbca21325b0a2d3a59be3dee1b3551

Comment: share more details such as package.json

Comment: updated with link to package.json